# How can I modify response headers using webRequest.onHeadersRecieved?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I'm writing an extension that gives a Chrome (and Firefox) user the ability to selectively modify response headers. Mainly it's for QA people to test that the front-end handles error modes properly (e.g. if a given route returns a 500, then the correct dialog displays).

This implementation uses the [Chrome webRequest API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#type-HttpHeaders).I know that the extension is loading, and I can block requests with `listener1`. However, `listener2` does not behave as expected, as it neither modifies the status code nor does it add the *josh* header. I have verified this in Chrome's network monitor tab. Both filters work, as far as it goes (I was testing with an explicit https filter because I know the webRequest API doesn't work with `file://` urls.)

As part of my troubleshooting process, I've disabled all other Chrome extensions, so I'm pretty sure nothing else is modifying headers.

```
let count = 0;

function listener1(details){
    return {cancel: true};
}
function listener2(details){
    console.log(count++, details);
    if (!details) return;
    for (let i = 0; i < details.responseHeaders.length; i++){
        if (details.responseHeaders[i].name === 'status'){
            details.responseHeaders[i].value = '500';
            break;
        }
    }
    details.responseHeaders.push({name: 'josh', value: 'count: ' + count});
    // Response is of type "Blocking Response"
    return {responseHeaders: details.responseHeaders};
}

const filter1 = '<all_urls>';
const filter2 = 'https://www.google.com/'

chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(listener2, { urls: [filter2] }, ['blocking', 'responseHeaders']);
```

Here is my manifest:

```
{
    "name": "Server Error Simulation Extension",
    "description" : "Base Level Extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_icon": "logo.png"
    },
    "background": {
        "persistent": true,
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "storage",
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking",
        "*://*.com/"
    ]
}
```

Note that I'm only wanting to modify headers, so this [Chrome bug about modifying response bodies](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=104058%20cannot%20modify%20response%20body%20//%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onHeadersReceived%20//%20https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/%20/master/extensions/common/api/web_request.json) doesn't apply. Also, [Firefox copied this API from Chrome](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onHeadersReceived) so I've tagged Firefox as well.

Comment: Your URL filter applies only to the main page on google's site. Add * at the end. Also beware of international variations. `"*://*.com/"` is invalid/weird - it matches main page of the site only.

Comment: @wOxxOm No, filtering is not the problem. I know this because when you use listener1 instead, the access is totally blocked. Also, there is a logging statement, and I've set debug breakpoints in there - if filtering was the issue, the listener callback would never be called.

Comment: AFAIK status is not a header so you can't modify it. As for the headers, try to copy the original array instead of modifying it e.g. var headers = [].concat(details.responseHeaders, [{name: 'josh', value: 'count: ' + count}])

Comment: I guess devtools network monitor always shows the original headers.

Comment: The status line is officially not a header. See https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html. Therefore the only way to do what I want to do is with an external proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer: HTTP status is not a header, according to the [RFC 2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html) which defines HTTP 1.1. Status is it's own thing, called a *Status-Line*. And it does look different, textually, since it doesn't have a *key:* prefix unlike everything else in the header.

As for why my custom header doesn't show up in network monitor, I'm not sure. Maybe it's a bug in the devtools, or something else.

In any event, whether or not its officially a header, the Chrome webRequest API exposes it as a "status" header, and I believe it should support modification in a way consistent with other headers.